# Button on click w/ selected value of <select> as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, freemarker

I am new to web development and I'm trying to do this: 
I have a `<select>` and I want the value of the selected option to be one of the parameters of a method that is called whenever a button is clicked.

So for example:

```
<select id="instructorSelector">
   <option value='abrown@gmail.com'>Anna Brown</option>
   <option value='jdoe@gmail.com'>Jane Doe</option>
   ...
</select>

<button onclick="sendEmail(($('#instructorSelector').val()),...,...)" type="button">Send Email</button>
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't seen to detect when I've actually selected someone. I'm using freemarker templates but a general response as to how I should do this would be helpful too.

Also, how could I make it so the button is not clickable (or even visible) until the user actually selects something from the `<select>` ?

Thanks in advance! Sorry if this is an overly simple question.

Comment: Do you have a `please select instructor` option in your `select` dropdown? If not, then technically you have the first `option` selected by default so loading the page and clicking the button will send an email to Anna Brown.

Comment: To select an element by id with jQuery, you must prefix the id with `#`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything, what you need is a proper event handler:

```
<select id="instructorSelector">
   <option value='abrown@gmail.com'>Anna Brown</option>
   <option value='jdoe@gmail.com'>Jane Doe</option>
   ...
</select>

<button id="btn" type="button">Send Email</button>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn').hide();

    $('#instructorSelector').on('change', function() {
        $('#btn').show();
    });

    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
        var select_value = $('#instructorSelector').val();

        // use the value here
    });
});
```

Comment: there is a bug if i want to choose 1st instructor there would be no way to press submit...until i experiment and choose 2nd one or other one than choose 1st one. Only then the button will show up.

Comment: wasn't that what you wanted, to have the button become visible after the user selects something. The change event is only fired if the user actually selects something, only other option is to use the click event which fill fire when the user clicks the select.

Comment: lol not paying attention eh... maybe!..i am not da questioner..:D
Either, way it makes for very odd and bad UI if default is an option but can't be chosen dont you think. But can be chosen after other choices have bee chosen. Default Should be "please select" etc

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it like this:

- disable the button in the beginning using the proper `disabled`-attribute
- toggle this attribute if the value of the box changes, depending on something is selected or not
- store the selectors in variables, so you don't need to re-query them all the time

**HTML**

```
<select id="instructorSelector">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="abrown@gmail.com">Anna Brown</option>
    <option value="jdoe@gmail.com">Jane Doe</option>
</select>

<button class="send_email" type="button" disabled="disabled">Send E-mail</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// example of a selector using a class name
var button = $('button.send_email');
// example of using a selector using the id of an element
var selector = $('#instructorSelector');

selector.change(function () {
    if ('' == selector.val()) {
        button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        button.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});

button.click(function(event) {
    sendEmail(selector.val());
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/rA4VJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.chage()` from jQuery http://api.jquery.com/change/ to make button visible

```
$('#instructorSelector').change(function () {
    $('#id-of-the-button').show();
});
```

In this chang function you can also capture values of option `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, you can have the property onchange on the select, that can trigger a method that could check the value and make visible the the button. Use an option to indicate that there is no selection, and if that is the one selected, hide the button.

```
<select id="instructorSelector" onchange="something()">
   <option value='selectone'>Select one</option>
   <option value='abrown@gmail.com'>Anna Brown</option>
   <option value='jdoe@gmail.com'>Jane Doe</option>
   ...
</select>
<button id="button" style="display:none;" onclick="sendEmail(($('instructorSelector').val()),...,...)" type="button">Send     Email</button>


function something(){
if ( $('#instructorSelector').val()!='selectone' ) {
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = 'block';
}
else{
    document.getElementById("button").style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you read [jQuery Event Basics](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/)

You will need to understand how you can use selectors along with events to truly leverage the power of jQuery.

I think after reading about events you will see how `click` and `change` will greatly benefits the goals you have for your page.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Way: http://jsfiddle.net/rA4VJ/

```
<select id="instructorSelector">
   <option value='none' selected>Choose Someone</option>
   <option value='abrown@gmail.com'>Anna Brown</option>
   <option value='jdoe@gmail.com'>Jane Doe</option>
</select>

<button id="btn" type="button">Send Email</button>

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var elm = document.getElementById("instructorSelector");

elm.onchange = function (e) {
    if (elm.value != 'none') {
        console.log(elm.value);
        btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
    } else {
        btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```